# Exclude directory while compressing using tar

Tags: shell, tar

I have a directory say "DIR" which contains so many directories say "A", "B" and "C"

I want to tar DIR without including "C" in it so that DIR.tar.gz does not contain the directory "C".

What is the shell command for this?

Thanks,
LinuxPenseur

Comment: This seems like a question for [Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/ask?tags=tar) or [Unix and Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=tar+command-line)

Comment: That's not "destination directory" - it's excluding a source directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your command line, something like this:

```
tar -cf archive.tar --exclude C DIR
```

Also, to nitpick your question, tar does not perform compression.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
tar --exclude="C" -czvf D.tar.gz DIR
```